# WinCE barcode scanner - COM Exception when initializing CCoreScannerClass

Tags: windows-ce

I am following this tutorial (https://atgsupportcentral.motorolasolutions.com/content/emb/docs/manuals/14978403a.pdf), created a simple Windows Forms and successfully can debug it on the scanner (it's a Symbol MC3000).
However I am getting an exception when trying to initialize the CCoreScannerClass:

```
        //Instantiate CoreScanner Class
        CCoreScannerClass cCoreScannerClass = new CoreScanner.CCoreScannerClass();
```

The exact error message is this:

"COM object with CLSID '{9F8D4F16-0F61-4A38-98B3-1F6F80F11C87}' cannot be created due to the following error: 0x80040154."

Can anyone please provide some help? Since it's a COM exception, I assume it's because the class is not registered? Any ideas on how to fix this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by downloading the EMDK for .NET from the Motorola's website:

https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=88177&productDetailGUID=f5563b1ca4151410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=a0bde8cea8151410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD

Comment: Be aware that the installation of the EMDK requires Visual studio 2005 or Visual Studio 2008. At least, I couldn't install it with my VS 2010 saying he couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

`0x80040154` is an error that, as you mentioned, pertains to the COM class not being registered, which means that COM couldn't find the class factory in the Windows registry. You can use `C:\Windows\system32\regsvr32` to register the missing SDK DLL.

Comment: I get an error - The module was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.
Make sure that it is a valid DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after the installation of the Scanner Management Service 
https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=87864&productDetailGUID=f0acd085364cf310VgnVCM10000081c7b10aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=84a76e203763e310VgnVCM1000000389bd0aRCRD