# .NET 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX}

Tags: c#, .net, com, regasm

I´m trying to run [COM.Scanner](https://github.com/josephrodriguez/miscelaneas.git) project but the follow exception is thrown:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {9F8D4F16-0F61-4A38-98B3-1F6F80F11C87} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Like `Interop.CoreScanner` is a .NET assembly I use `regasm` to register the COM objects, but the error still occurs.

I come to read this good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036856/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-xxxx-failed-due-to-t) but none of answers solved the problem.

This the information of [Corflags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework CorFlags Conversion Tool.  Version  4.6.81.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Version   : v2.0.50727
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 0x1
ILONLY    : 1
32BITREQ  : 0
32BITPREF : 0
Signed    : 0
```

The generated `.reg` file with `regasm` and `/regfile` option is:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{9F8D4F16-0F61-4A38-98B3-1F6F80F11C87}\InprocServer32]
"Class"="CoreScanner.CCoreScannerClass"
"Assembly"="Interop.CoreScanner, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
"CodeBase"="file:///D:/Github/miscelaneas/COM.Scanner/libs/Interop.CoreScanner.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{9F8D4F16-0F61-4A38-98B3-1F6F80F11C87}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0]
"Class"="CoreScanner.CCoreScannerClass"
"Assembly"="Interop.CoreScanner, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
"CodeBase"="file:///D:/Github/miscelaneas/COM.Scanner/libs/Interop.CoreScanner.dll"
```

Environment:

- OS: Windows 10 (x64)
- Visual Studio 2015

**QUESTION**

- This smells like that there are missing entries on registry, but I don´t know which.
- If I´m in the right way why `regasm` is not able to generate the missing registry entries?

Comment: Never, *never*, **never** register an interop library.  You must register the native COM component instead, using Regsvr32.exe or (preferably) the vendor's installer.  If you don't have that installer then use a telephone, looks like you need to call Zebra.  If you did have it then your use of Regasm.exe destroyed the install, you'll have to re-install.

Comment: If I don´t want as requirements to the clients install a SDK I need a native COM component and register it with Regsvr32.exe?

Comment: Again, use a telephone to talk to the vendor and ask for specific install advice.  Asking for a merge module that you can integrate with your own installer is best.

Comment: Obviously my knowledge about COM is not of most advanced, then any final consumer of native component let say on X language need a compiled Interop library on X?, that works as a bridge? Since I published the question had great faith in you were going to clarify the doubts @Hans. Grateful.

Comment: I recently ran into this exact same problem. It required me finding a machine which the program ran successfully, then checking the registry for the key and running regsvr32.exe on it: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197506/how-to-repair-comexception-error-80040154]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440900/wince-barcode-scanner-com-exception-when-initializing-ccorescannerclass) that the missing component is installed together with Motorolas [**EMDK SDK**](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=88177&productDetailGUID=f5563b1ca4151410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=a0bde8cea8151410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD). Installing the SDK should solve your issue.

Registering the interop assembly does not take you any further, as the interop assembly is just a library containing the type definitions of the COM component so that you are able to compile your C# code with static typing and early binding. The actual thing that needs to be registered is the underlying COM component. To register that you would use `regasm.exe` only if the actual COM component if the COM component was written in .NET. Otherwise you need to use the classic `regsvr32.exe` (or use the installer of the component vendor).

Comment: I solved with that link. Also installing the Scanner SDK [here](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/scanning-systems/scanner-drivers-and-utilities/scanner-sdk-for-windows.html) solve the problem.